Flutter apps hangs up in simulator after launching a url (e.g. URL Launcher)
I am developing a Flutter app and using the url_launcher package to open URLs. The app works fine on Android and older versions of iOS, but when I test it on iOS 18 using the simulator, the app hangs after launching the URL.
Here’s the code I’m using to launch the URL:
Future<void> _launchURL(Uri url) async {
  if (await canLaunchUrl(url)) {
    await launchUrl(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}

The URL launches correctly, but immediately afterward, the app becomes unresponsive, and I have to stop the simulator to continue. This issue only occurs on iOS 18; it works fine on older versions.
Steps to Reproduce:
1.  Install the url_launcher package in the Flutter app.
2.  Use the code above to launch a URL.
3.  Run the app on an iOS 18 simulator.
4.  Attempt to launch a URL.

Expected Behavior:
The URL should open, and the app should remain responsive.
Actual Behavior:
The URL launches, but the app hangs afterward and becomes unresponsive.
Environment:
•   Flutter: 3.24.3 (Stable branch)
•   iOS Simulator: iOS 18
•   url_launcher: ^6.3.0

Has anyone else encountered this issue? Any suggestions for resolving it would be greatly appreciated!
PS: The app also hangs when I use the sign with Google functionality (also launching an in App browser) and Stripe checkout with PayPal functionality.

Update the url_launcher package,
Future<void> _launchURL(Uri url) async {
  if (await canLaunchUrl(url)) {
    await launchUrl(
      url,
      mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication,
    );
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}

Try this,

Hi Thanks for you answer. As this resolves the issue with the url_launcher as it now just opens Safari, the issue persists when I use sign in with Google or the PayPal checkout of Stripe as both of them natively open the in app browser.
Any Ideas how fix the issue for them?

check below code  for customoption

import 'package:flutter_custom_tabs/flutter_custom_tabs.dart';

Future<void> _launchURL(String url) async {
  try {
    await launch(
      url,
      option: CustomTabsOption(
        toolbarColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        enableDefaultShare: true,
        enableUrlBarHiding: true,
        showPageTitle: true,
        animation: CustomTabsAnimation.slideIn(),
      ),
    );
  } catch (e) {
    // Handle error
  }
}

Try this for google and paypal checkout
